# Редирект на страницу без повторяющихся слешей с помощью .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

```
# Редирект на страницу без повторяющихся /.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=301,L]
```

`THE_REQUEST` используется вместо `REQUEST_URI`, т.к. иначе не сработает редирект с `site///page.htm`l на `site/page.html`, т.к. `REQUEST_URI` содержит в себе часть адреса после последнего слеша.

Проблема в том, что `THE_REQUEST` содержит и параметры GET запроса. В случае запроса: `site/page.html?//` возникнет ошибка `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

**Вопрос:** как реализовать редирект на страницу без повторяющихся слешей, но при этом не проверять слеши в параметре GET запроса после `?` чтобы не возникала ошибка `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (^[^?]*)
RewriteCond %1 //
RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=301,L]
```

Короче обрезаю полный запрос до ? а потом в этой обрезанной части ищу //. Вроде работает. Не знаю почему такую штуку на других сайтах не используют.